# MultipartEntity Android sending zip file but not able to save it in php

Tags: java, php, android, post, multipartentity

Im sending data using MulitpartEntity, I know zip file is being sent, I can loop it in php but for some reason the type returns empty.

```
if($_FILES["imagezip"]["name"]) {
    $type = $_FILES["imagezip"]["type"];
    $strLog .= $type . " type\n";
}
```

it keeps on failing when I try to move it

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagezip']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    $strLog .= "success\n";
} else{
    $strLog .= "fail\n";
}
```

Here is how I am sending the file

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // You can use get method too here if you use get at the php scripting side to receive any values.
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    multipartEntity.addPart("json", new StringBody(mPost));
    multipartEntity.addPart("imagezip", new FileBody(mfile));
    httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);


    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parmeters));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
```